# How to join three different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm using MySQL v5.5

I was simply `left joining` two tables and getting my accurate data.

But as soon as I tried to add another table in here, the results are not accurate.

[Here is the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=8b67d0bcb9a5062ff79e5171afb32e43)

Do tell what am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: While joining more than one table in a query which uses aggregate functions you will observe an inaccuracy known as joining multiplying. Each row in 1st joined table will have as many copies as the amount of rows in 2nd joined table for the same row in main table. Solution - aggregate in subquery then join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple matches in each table for a given event, so the joins multiply the rows, and you get wrong results.

I would recommend pre-aggregating in subqueries:

```
select e.event_id, e.title, e.description, e.event_date, e.image, 
    coalesce(d.total_amount,0) as total,
    coalesce(d.total_donors, 0) as total_donors,
    coalesce(v.total_volunteers, 0) as total_volunteers
from event e 
left join (
    select event_id, count(*) as total_volunteers
    from volunteer 
    group by event_id
) v on v.event_id = e.event_id
left join (
    select event_id, sum(amount) as total_amount, count(*) as total_donors
    from donation 
    group by event_id
) d on d.event_id = e.event_id
```

Comment: Another question: Will the subquery executes a bit slower considering I have 5-6k rows of data?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to remove the **LEFT**, leave it just as **JOIN**, I had the same issue once and this [tutorial](https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-join-3-tables-or-more-in-sql/) really helped me

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. This may have helped in your scenario but didn't work for me.Thanks for the reply though :)